# OutOfMemoryException in c# when deserializing XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, stream

I have an object in c# that needs to be saved as file and reused.

So basically what I am doing now is I am serializing a class to xml and I am saving it as a file. The file is aproximatelly 100MB.

Now the problem I am experiencing is when I want to deserialize file to class, I and up with OutOfMemoryException.

I am using the following code:

```
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(file);

Deserialize<T>(xmlDocument.InnerXml);

 public static T Deserialize<T>(string xmlContent)
 {
     var inStream = new StringReader(xmlContent);
     var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
     return (T)ser.Deserialize(inStream);
 }
```

Comment: Why do you do `xmlDocument.InnerXml`, that seems odd.

Comment: If it's a really big file, you might experience an out of memory exception due to it being two times + overhead in your memory. Instead of reading the string (and thus storing it in memory) and then passing it to the Deserialize method, you could probably just pass a FileStream directly to your deserializer.

Comment: @Rosenheimer let me try you suggestion...

Comment: Just to clarify, you'll not use the XmlDocument at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what my comment would look like in code:

```
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string Filepath)
    {
        using (FileStream FStream = new FileStream(Filepath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            var Deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)Deserializer.Deserialize(FStream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is what i just did. It solves the outofmemory issue. But in case anyone reads this question in the future, iis express will have a lot of outofmemoryexception which are resolved using iis.

Comment: "...which are resolved using iis." -Did you mean "...which are resolved using this."? If not, where are you getting additional exceptions?

Comment: your solution made it work on iis express. without your solution is does not work on iis express, but it works on iis. Optimizing memory usage is the key, but iis will tolerate more costly solutions then iis express. At the moment I also work on additional largers streams without saving them to files, so outofmemoryexception is such an often case with large files on iis express.